# Connection between series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I have to show that if  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$ is absolutely convergent too.

Please give me some hint, how do I start the excercise. Thanks!

Comment: To call "absolutely" convergent to $\;\sum a_n^2\;$ is redundant as this is a positive series.

Comment: Hint: when does the square of a number get smaller in absolute value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First show that there exist $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ you have $|a_n|<1$. Then compare the tails of the two sums.

Comment: Or directly:$$|a_n|<1\implies a_n^2<|a_n|$$ and the comparison test kicks in. +1

Comment: I wanted to keep something for the OP...

Comment: You did, @Quimey, yet "the tails" may be way messier than the comparison test. Yet, the OP still *has* to justify some stuff...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint if the terms are all positive: suppose that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges. Then $|a_n| \to 0$, and $\dfrac{a_n^2}{|a_n|} \to 0$ as well. Apply the limit comparison test.